# debug a google apps script

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I don't uderstand why my function doesn't recognize the 'e' from the onEdit function?
Do you have an idea?
Thank's a lot if you can help me
[the error when i try to debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8sUq.png)

```html
function onEdit(e){
  
  var feuille = e.source;
  if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getColumn()==7){  //the 7th column is the "+/-" column
    var i = e.source.getActiveRange().getRow(); //i is the line of the change
    var k = 408+i;   // k is the line where we put the date
    var l = 2;       //l is the column where we put the date and the quantity
    var cellDate = feuille.getRange(k,l);  
    while (isEmpty(cellDate)==false){  //the column of the date is incremented 
      l=l+1;
    }
    feuille.getRange(k,l).setValue(new Date());
    const stockDate = feuille.getRange(i,8).getValue();
      feuille.getRange(k+1,8).setValue(stockDate);
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();   
    spreadsheet.getRange("G2:G403").setValue('0');  ////we reset the "+/-" column to zero

  }    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onEdit(e)` function is a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) that is designed to run automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet. In that context, the event object `e` is properly populated.

If you blindly run your `onEdit(e)` function in the script editor, the event parameter `e` is not populated, causing the error you mention.

You can debug your `onEdit(e)` function by writing a wrapper function that creates an object and uses it as parameter when calling `onEdit(e)`, like this:

```
function testOnEdit() {
  const e = {
    source: SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
  };
  onEdit(e);
}
```

Then debug the `testOnEdit()` function.

See [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).